# How to make a queue of NSURLRequest using GCD?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, nsurlconnection, grand-central-dispatch

I have a `NSMutableArray` containing 7 internet `URLs` from which I need to grab the `HTTP` headers.

I'm using these methods to make `asynchronous` connections (and all works perfectly):

```
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveResponse:(NSURLResponse *)response
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didReceiveData:(NSData *)data
- (void)connection:(NSURLConnection *)connection didFailWithError:(NSError *)error
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection
```

The problem is that I need to download each `URL` following the order of the `NSMutableArray`, but due to the nature of the `asynchronous` connection the order gets messed up.

I don't want to use `synchronous` connections because they block the `Main Thread.`

How do I make a queue using `GCD` on the `Main Thread` to ensure that the downloads will follow the order of indexes from 0 to 6 of my `NSMutableArray` containing the 7 `URLs`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You do not need GCD for that. You can start with the first download, and in `connectionDidFinishLoading` or `didFailWithError` start the next download. You would only need to maintain an index of the current download, so that you know if you are finished or which download to start next.

The following is just a sketch of this idea:

```
// Start the first download:
self.currentDownload = 0;
request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self.myURLArray objectAtIndex:0]];
connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];

// and in connectionDidFinishLoading/didFailWithError:
self.currentDownload++;
if (self.currentDownload < self.myURLArray.count) {
    request = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[self.myURLArray objectAtIndex:self.currentDownload]];
    connection = [NSURLConnection connectionWithRequest:request delegate:self];
} else {
     // All downloads finished.
}
```

Comment: I'm iterating the NSMutable Array before. How would I accomplish what you said in the connectionDidFinishLoading method? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Winston: I have added some sample code, perhaps it helps. Using `NSOperation` is of course also an option, as @tgt suggested.

Comment: Just add a private property to hold the current index.  Start the first one off and then continue the process in the delegate method using the next index # (increment it after)

Comment: Hi Martin, the code worked like a charm! Thanks a lot man, I learned one more ObjC trick with you :-)

Comment: Hello @MartinR, I running through a for loop creating different JSON data and passing to the request. So suppose my array count is 4, then I making 4 requests.. This works fine, but this is asynchronous and all calls trigger at once.. What I want to achieve is that, after first request in loop finishes and returns response I want to call second request with new JSON, because I have to pass some response returned by first request in second and so on.. So how this can be done.

Comment: @Ranjit: That is exactly what the above code does. `connectionDidFinishLoading` is called when a connection has finished downloaded, so you can prepare the request and start the next connection.

Comment: Hello @MartinR, can you look at this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25885317/start-nsurlconnection-requests-serially

Answer (score 1):

I think the other solution is rather inflexible and it might be nicer to do this using NSOperation. A nice introduction to it can be found on [NSHipster](http://nshipster.com/nsoperation/) and [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/NSOperationQueue_class/Reference/Reference.html). There're also several Stack Overflow questions about this topic and [this](http://www.cocoabuilder.com/archive/cocoa/279826-nsurlrequest-and-nsoperationqueue.html).

Comment: Thanks, and I'm checking NSOperationQueue.