# How to run NSURLConnection for number of times one by one

Tags: ios, xcode, nsurlconnection

I am using `NSURLConnection` for the connection request to get json file from the server and put the data in the dB. But now I have to make multiple requests in array i.e. one-by-one to server, requesting each time after completion of parsing and writing to dB. I am totally confused how to do this. Please help me out.

Comment: There are probably several good ways to do this, one is described in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12143659/how-to-make-a-queue-of-nsurlrequest-using-gcd/12144059#12144059.

Answer (score 2):

This is quite simple put all your NSURLRequests in a Queue (can be an simple array).
Then run the first request (objectAtIndex:0 because we are operating with a queue). 
And in the connection did finish method do the following:

```
- (void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection;
{
    //Handle your db save
    //...
    //get next object
    if([self.queue count] > 0) {
        NSURLReuest *nextRequest = [self.queue objectAtIndex:0];
        [self.queue removeObjectAtIndex:0];
        NSURLConnection *con = [connectionWithRequest:nextRequest delegate:self];
        [con start];
    } else {...}
}
```

Be careful, the above code is not checked and just written out of my mind... So it may contain some syntax errors... What I wanted to show you is the principle on how to solve such an issue

Comment: for the sake of the answer, maybe you would like to add deleting the queue index that has fired (right under starting connection)

Comment: hi, thanks, It worked!! thanks again, happy :), the thing is i followed both of you, @Alexander and Martin R's link, actually there was problem with remove object so. But main thing is it worked. :D Thanks a lot!!!