# Start NSURLConnection requests serially

Tags: ios, nsurlconnection

I'm looping through an array which contains few strings and making a request to a web server for each
strings in the array.

I would like each request to be processed completely before the subsequent request is sent to the server. Because each request sends me a response which I will send with next request and so on.

The problem I am having is that my NSURLConnection is set up using the standard asynchronous call. This results in requests not blocking any subsequent requests. But I need to block other requests in the loop before first completes.

The request URL is same always , only JSON data changes with every request in the loop.
Here is my code

```
for (int i = 0; i < array.count; i++)
{


     NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalJSON options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
     if (!jsonData) {
                NSLog(@"Error creating JSON object: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
            }


      NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@“abc.com/folders”];

      NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

      [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
      [request setValue:APIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X_API_KEY"];

      [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
      [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];

            //I am adding all connections to NSDictionary so that later I can process request.
      NSURLConnection *connection = [self connectionForRequest:request];
      [connection start];                

}
```

Comment: What's the problem??? "The problem I am having is that my NSURLConnection is set up using the standard asynchronous call. This results in requests not blocking any subsequent requests."???

Comment: Hey @gran33, I want to start the second connection only when I get response from first..but here what is happening is that, requests are made in parallel

Comment: that was a type mistake...just see my updated edit

Comment: Ok, see my next answer...

Comment: @Ranjit - consider a recursive solution.

Answer (score 1):

I thought of 2 solutions for your problem:

1. [AFNetworking](https://github.com/AFNetworking/AFNetworking) - U can use `AFNetworking` and maintain a counter in the success block. The counter will count the requests and when all done, will do your next task.
2. GCD - [Dispatch Groups](http://www.raywenderlich.com/63338/grand-central-dispatch-in-depth-part-2) - Grand Central Dispatch provide u the option to make group or requests and do something at the end (when all the requests finished). For that, u need to read nice tutorial (2nd part of "Ray Wenderlich". If U r not familiar with GCD, jump to the tutorial 1st part).

Anyway, With your code above U can't achieve your task. U don't have any async block which run at the end of the requests.

**Edit:**

Use AFNetworking:

U must remove your for loop first, and then do like this:

```
AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
NSDictionary *parameters = @{@"foo": @"bar"};
[manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { // HERE u can do your second request which uses the first response

        AFHTTPRequestOperationManager *manager = [AFHTTPRequestOperationManager manager];
        NSDictionary *parameters_new = <USE_YOUR_DATA_FROM_responseObject>;
        [manager POST:@"http://example.com/resources.json" parameters:parameters      success:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, id responseObject) { // HERE u can do your third request which uses the first and second response



        } failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
             NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
        }]; 


} failure:^(AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation, NSError *error) {
    NSLog(@"Error: %@", error);
}];
```

Comment: hello @gran33 thanks, I dont want to do some task after finishing all the requests, For eg, suppose my array count is 4, then when I run inside the loop it will make 4 requests, So inside this only I want to block other 3 requests till first one completes with response and so on

Comment: m8?..Can you please tell me what you have understood and what not..so that I can explain you better.

Comment: m8 = mate ;) 
I didn't understand this:"
So inside this only I want to block other 3 requests till first one completes with response and so on"

Comment: Ok let me explain , I have an array which contains few strings, and each string I have to pass with separate request.So I am running the loop and making 4 request and passing the string in JSON format.So when I send first string with first request, it will return me a response , so for the second request I should send some value from first response and so on... But presently what is happening is that calls are fired immediately one after the other without waiting for the response from the previous request.

Comment: Hey @gran so is this making a synchronous call? I have not used AFNetworking, So I need to learn it first. If I remove the for loop, How do I know how many requests to make?

Comment: AFNetworking is #1 iOS/OSX networking API, U better learn it and use it by default (it's super easy to use).
No, for your question, As u can see, I nested the requests, so the success block of the first request make the second request and so on.
U can consider make a simple recursion, but u better avoid to do this. Your considerations.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61398/discussion-between-ranjit-and-gran33).

Answer (score 0):

A simple way to do this is with recursion.  Create a method that sends the url connection, and, once the connection is complete, calls itself to send it again.

Here's the key to the solution:  make a method that can be called recursively, which sends requests and collects results.  By calling itself recursively in the completion block, this method sees to it that each request starts after the previous one finishes...

```
// note - edited per the comments to get a new NSURLRequest each time
- (void)makeRequests:(NSInteger)count
             results:(NSMutableArray *)results
          completion:(void (^)(NSError *))completion {

    // complete recursion
    if (count == 0) return completion(nil);

    NSURLRequest *request = [self nextRequest];

    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:request queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *error) {

        if (!error) {
            [results addObject:data];
            [self makeRequests:count-1 results:results completion:completion];
        } else {
            completion(error);
        }
    }];
}
```

To call it, allocate an array that will carry the results...

```
- (void)makeManyRequests {

    NSMutableArray *resultsArray = [NSMutableArray array];
    [self makeRequests:10 results:resultsArray completion:^(NSError *error) {
        NSLog(@"done.  results are %@", resultsArray);
    }];
}
```

**EDIT** - Its unclear in the OP how this request changes each time, but it sounds like you have that figured out.  This is just your originally posted code in its own method.  Its a good idea to factor this out so your code can be clear on how it forms a different JSON payload each time...

```
- (NSURLRequest *)nextRequest {

    id finalJSON = // your app supplies...
    // somehow, this changes each time nextRequest is called

    NSString *APIKEY = // your app supplies
    NSError *error;

    NSData *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization dataWithJSONObject:finalJSON options:NSJSONWritingPrettyPrinted error:&error];
    if (!jsonData) {
        NSLog(@"Error creating JSON object: %@", [error localizedDescription]);
    }

    // your request creation code, copied from the OP
    NSString *url = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"abc.com/folders"];

    NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]];

    [request setValue:@"application/json;charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [request setValue:APIKEY forHTTPHeaderField:@"X_API_KEY"];
    [request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [request setHTTPBody:jsonData];
    return request;
}
```

Comment: Hello @danh thanks for you answer, as you said my code does the same thing, but I am using the loop because everytime I am sending new json. JSON data changes with each request made

Comment: please post how the json changes each time.  the currently posted code shows the same variable, finalJSON being serialized each time.  Is it changing in the loop?  Back at my desk in a few hours...

Comment: @Ranjit - still not sure _how_ the json changes, but edited answer to assume it does.  you should be able to work out how to change it each time.